# how to use readAsDataURL function to get the name of local file

Tags: javascript

I want to use this method "readAsDataURL(input.files[0]),"--line 3 ---to get the url for the local file.But I'm not sure if it returns a string or not. When I put something like"sample.pdf" it works well. Is it returns a string? If not, how can I cast the local file name to string so it can be read in?

function readURL3(input) {

```
        var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 

            url: readAsDataURL(input.files[0]),   
            pdfOpenParams: {
                navpanes: 0,
                toolbar: 0,
                scrollbar: 0,
                statusbar: 0,
                view: "FitV"
            }

        }).embed("pdf");


};
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to use `input.files[0].name`